# Call parameter if variable true

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports

the following question is about a Jasper-Report:

Can i call a parameter, when a variable becomes true?
I want to call a parameter more than once, to write something in specific chosen fields.

Thanks for your answeres.

Greetings, Robert

Comment: What do you mean "call a parameter"?

Comment: In iReport i can use parameters to fill a variable with a value or textfields with a string. I want a variable, to call a parameter so that i can fill a texfield with the text I typed in, every time the variable is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, iReport only prompts for parameters at the beginning of the report-filling process. This is because all of the parameter values must be set before the process starts. Once the filling has started, the parameters cannot be changed.

(From reading your comment on your other question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473244/dynamic-text-input, I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want using iReport or JasperReports on its own. JasperReports was not designed to have an interactive report-filling process.)